# alpha attribute in XML can't be found in Android

Tags: android, alpha

Android Studio can't find  in XML and is required to fix the path,

Please help me with this. Do I need to install something else?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    />
```

[image]

Actually alpha doesn't need to set the width & height

Comment: I posted, please check out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that you placed your anim xml in your layout folder which is an error in android studio instead you need to create a folder for animation:

**sample:**

```
right click `res` ->  new -> Android resource file -> Directory name anim && filename is the name of your xml -> ok
```

after that it will generate an xml file just replace paste your anim xml in there.

Comment: @KyeongsikJasonKim anytime :))